# Flutter - How can I make a widget transparent in a page view as I'm changing the page?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm trying to make a custom `PageView` transition that looks like the top view of a deck of cards, but I want the top view to become transparent as I'm scrolling through. I tried using an `Opacity` widget but it turns the widget white instead of making it transparent. How can I fix this?

This Is how it currently looks as I'm scrolling. It is a red view but it starts turning white and I need it to be slightly transparent.

[image: screen capture]

This is my current code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage()));

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final PageController controller = PageController();

  List<Widget> pages = <Widget>[
    Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: const Center(child: Text("0")),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: const Center(child: Text("1")),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: const Center(child: Text("2")),
    )
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
        itemCount: pages.length,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        controller: controller,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return DeckPageView(
            controller: controller,
            index: index,
            child: pages[index],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DeckPageView extends StatefulWidget {
  const DeckPageView({
    Key? key,
    required this.index,
    required this.controller,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final int index;
  final PageController controller;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  DeckPageViewState createState() => DeckPageViewState();
}

class DeckPageViewState extends State<DeckPageView> {
  double _pagePosition = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (widget.controller.position.haveDimensions) {
        widget.controller.addListener(() {
          if (mounted) {
            setState(() => _pagePosition = widget.controller.page!);
          }
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double delta = _pagePosition - widget.index;
    return ClipRect(
      child: Transform.translate(
        offset: _pagePosition.floor() != widget.index
            ? Offset(0, -MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * delta.abs())
            : const Offset(0, 0),
        child: Opacity(
          opacity: _pagePosition.floor() != widget.index ? 1 : 1 - _pagePosition + widget.index,
          child: widget.child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using Opacity in Opacity add Container add give that container color:tranform.translate  here is what you do in your Widget build

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  double delta = _pagePosition - widget. Index;
  return ClipRect(
  child: Transform.translate(
  offset: _pagePosition.floor() != widget. Index
      ? Offset(0, -MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * delta. Abs())
      : const Offset(0, 0),
  child: Opacity(
    opacity: _pagePosition.floor() != widget. Index ? 1 : 1 - _pagePosition + widget. Index,
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: widget. Child,
      ),
     ),
   ),
  );
 }
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I saw no visible change